# how to normalize the output of neural network in tensorflow 1

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have created a neural network using tensorflow 1.x as below:

```
def coder(x):
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['encoder_h1']),biases['encoder_b1']))
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['encoder_h2']), biases['encoder_b2']))
    layer_3 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['encoder_h3']),biases['encoder_b3']))
    return layer_3
```

What I need is to normalize the output of that neural network. I have tried to do that manually by:

```
layer_4 = (layer_3  * tf.sqrt(tf.cast(tf.shape(layer_3 )[0], dtype=tf.float32))) / tf.norm(layer_3 ) 
return layer_4
```

But, I think this way is not correct, is there a way I can normalize the output of the neural network such as adding a normalization layer or something like that.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0 has feature of normalizing the output of neural network. The feature is available in tf.keras that is `tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization`. For more details on Tensorflow layer normalization can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/layers_normalizations#layer_normalization_tutorial). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer how about Tensorflow 1.15 ? is there any solution for that ?

Comment: As per my understanding Normalization is available only in Tf 2.x.